# Na semana que entra?

Tags: ortografia, verbos, concordância-verbal

Já ouvi expressões como os exemplos a seguir:

> Na semana que entra vou viajar.
>   No mês que entra comemoramos o Natal.

É correto falar "semana que entra" ou "mês que entra"?

Comment: Pelo menos na região onde moro, é mais comum dizer "Na semana que vem.".

Comment: No Brasil é mais comum usar "mês que vem", "semana que vem" mas não é raro ouvir essa expressão

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Está corretíssimo. Vê por exemplo [***entrar*** no Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/entrar):

> (4) Ter início; ABRIR; COMEÇAR [int[ransitivo] : "Quando entrar setembro..." ( Beto Guedes , "Sol de primavera") ]